# Trying to determine safe header span for clear opening on existing remodel

Tags: doors, framing, load-bearing, beam, engineering

[image][image][image][image]I have a house which has a footprint of roughly 40 feet long and 24 feet wide. On the side in question, one of the 24' sides, there is an existing 4 panel glass door system in place. This room has 10' ceilings. The second story load in this room is carried by (3) 2x8x12's as a beam. This beam terminates at the side of the home above the glass panels. There is a cripple stud truss (for lack of a better description) where this beam terminates and the load is carried down onto (2) 2x12x14 or 16, I don't have an exact measure of the length but its between 14' and 16'. The actual clear opening for the sliding doors is 12'. And the double 2x12x14/16 is supported on either side by several 2x4's.

This house is from the 60's or 70's so this structure did work and continues to but I am looking for some kind of confirmation of this design through consultation of appropriate span tables. I've looked at some span tables for headers but I think the fact that the second story load terminates directly above this 12' span is something I can't account for as a laymen when I'm looking at span tables. A regular span table doesn't seem to consider carrying the central load from the second story bearing down on the middle of them. And today I assume they would use an engineered wood product or even an I beam in this place.

I'm looking for some education on what terminology I should be searching for or if there is a specific span table that takes this unique architecture into account.

Thanks

[image]

[image: house image]

Comment: Your header is a "transfer beam."

Comment: How long is your "beam carrying floor joist load"? Are these joists entirely under sleeping rooms? If not, then what percentage of the supported floor area carries sleeping areas?

Comment: Is there a hip roof with rafters bearing on the wall? Some other substantial roof load carried by the wall above your header? Is there a wall running parallel to the joist-carrying beam that could be transferring roof load down to the joist-carrying beam?

Answer (score 0):

Technically there could exist a table for your transfer beam. Analogous to the new deck footing table in the 2021 IRC, such a table would require you to understand the concept of "tributary area." I couldn't find such a table.

Your transfer beam has contributions from two elevations. For the contribution from the roof elevation, the tributary area is (13ft/2)(23ft/2) = 75ft². For 10 psf dead load and 30 psf snow load, that's (40psf)(75ft²) = 3000#. Not all of this load shows up at the transfer beam, however. Moving the load from the post bases to the carrier beam, the 3000# becomes (3000#)(8ft)/(12ft) = 2000# (the remaining 1000# shows up at the exterior walls). Moving the 2000# to the transfer beam, the 2000# becomes (2000#)(147in)/(177in) = 1700# (the remaining 300# shows up at the other end of the carrier beam). For this part of the analysis, I used the sleeping room width instead of the tapered roof width. The result is conservative.

For the load from the sleeping rooms, I use 10 psf for the dead load and 30 psf for the live load. The load contribution, then, is (40psf)(23ft/2)(14.75ft/2) = 3400#.

The total midspan load is 1700# + 3400# = 5100#.

**Deflection**

#2 Spruce-Pine-Fir has an elastic modulus of 1,400,000 psi. The IRC prescribes a minimum deflection of L/360 = (144in)/360 = 0.4in. For 30 psf live load from the sleeping room and 20 psf live load from the roof, I get a midspan live load of (1700#)(20psf)/(40psf) + (3400#)(30psf)/(40psf) = 3400#. Two 2×12s have a deflection of

(1/48)(3400#)(144in)³/[(1400000psi)(1/12)(3.0in)(11.5in)³] = 0.40in,

just barely satisfying the deflection requirement.

**Strength**

Assuming that the header takes 3 or more 2×12s, I use the NDS's 1.15 repetitive use factor. #2 Spruce-Pine-Fir has an adjusted bending strength of (1.15)(875psi) = 1010psi. The strength of a single 2x12, then, is

(1010psi)(1/6)(1.5in)(11.5in)² = 33300#-in.

Given the 5100# demand from earlier, the bending demand of the transfer beam is (5100#)(144in)/4 = 184000#-in. Taking (184000#-in)/(33300#-in) = 5.5, I find that you need 6 2×12s to satisfy the demand on the transfer beam.

Supplementing the existing pair of 2×12 with deeper LVLs or higher grade 2×12s is a bit complicated. You can't just add strengths for a beam that mixes LVLs and/or different grades. The problem is that different layers in such a beam fail at different loads, where the failed layers quickly lose strength. See Figures 6.24 and 6.25 from page 149 of [Computational modeling of strand-based wood composites in bending](https://open.library.ubc.ca/soa/cIRcle/collections/ubctheses/831/items/1.0075230). Looking up some random LVL data, it looks like a single 1-3/4"×16" LVL has sufficient strength without any contribution from the 2×12s. Maybe you can remove the cripple studs and install such an LVL tight to the underside of the carrier beam.

**Jack Studs**

The jack stud configuration is predicated on the solution implemented, so it will have to wait for more details from you.

**Other problems**

- Much of this analysis is moot if the carrier beams and/or joists don't have the strength to deliver the loads to the transfer beams.
- I compute a demand/capacity ratio of 1.5 for the roof elevation header assuming #2 Spruce-Pine-Fir. It needs a sister.
- Since the floor joists beneath the posts from the roof elevation haven't been modified in any way, they have effectively zero capacity beyond their walking surface duties. I suspect that their demand/capacity ratio is far worse than the downstairs transfer beam.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I think I will follow up with a local engineer and get his input. To summarize my understanding, it looks like I have enough jack studs but the header may be insufficient per code. A follow up question I have then is understanding the delta between modern code and absolute strength of this header, i.e, is it dangerous? Obviously it has stood the test of time and a builder wouldn't install it like this today in 2023 but is it dangerous and at risk of failure?

Comment: @Jimmy, I've used a 40 psf live load. It should be 30 psf if those are sleeping rooms above on the second floor. I've used #2 grade lumber of the common species for different US regions. If it is an exotic species (unlikely) or a better grade (quite possible), then I've underestimated its strength. I've assumed zero roof load, where something like a hip roof wrecks that assumption. I think that 40 psf live load goes _way_ back for strength computations. Your beam slenderness makes it decided by strength instead of deflection, so you get deflection control for free.

Comment: @Jimmy, 20 psf is a roof's live load (for construction guys and construction material during roof installation). Interior commercial parking garages get 40 psf live loads (although I suspect that this is currently changing). Libraries get 100 psf live loads. You get about 10 psf capacity for each ply (assuming grade and species), where your 2 plies get you about 10 psf live load capacity beyond the 10 psf dead load. Deflection is good, however, so it feels fine. It has been fine all this time, so I wouldn't hit the panic alarm. First thing should be searching for grade and species stamp(s).

Comment: @Jimmy, hacking that table for 2 plies like your current configuration, you're right at the transition point between 1 and 2 jack studs. Again, that's predicated on grade and species, however.

Comment: I found better photos with the wood exposed. It looks like #2 pine/fir with knots but that are about 1inch. Each side has 2 jack studs at the end of the clear opening and one additional near the king stud (3 total each side). I am wondering since your calculations suggest 4 2x12x16's if I could essentially double what is there in front of it. So essentially add two additional 2x12's with the same number of jack and king studs. This way it would essentially become a 4 ply header.

Comment: What I would wonder about there is how the truss shape wouldn't actually underpin the edge of the house if it was built in front of the existing truss and header. Although it would underpin the tributary 3 board beam and since it would be supported by the foundation below, the additive support should provide what is needed. Wood grade is pine/douglas fir. When you say "I would not cheat with only 4 plies" I am confused since your math suggests 4 would be adequate. Also, house has a flat rubber roof and roof joists are a mere 2x6x12. The room above this area is indeed a sleeping room.

Comment: @Jimmy, the analysis is predicated on no roof load and 40 psf live load instead of the 30 psf that would be appropriate for sleeping rooms. Does any load from the roof rafters find its way through the transfer beam? If so, then the geometry of the roof framing becomes important. Technically the 12'-0" span that I used was incorrect. For 1 jack stud at each end, the span becomes 12'-0"+3/4"+3/4". Treating the 4.01 as 4, then, is inappropriate because I cheated on the length and correcting would push the 4.01 up to something like 4.05 or 4.1. The point is moot because your species isn't Hem-Fir.

Comment: @Jimmy it sounds like you plan to sister new plies to the existing header without any bearing support below the new plies. Is this what you mean by underpinning the edge of the house? 2x4 jack studs are inadequate for supporting a header with more than 2 plies. Let me know for sure if there's additional loading from the roof so I can iterate the analysis with the 30 psf sleeping room spec and any additional roof load.

Comment: @Jimmy, 3 plies of structural select grade is also probably an option assuming that additional load from the roof doesn't disrupt things terribly. Just a thought if the 4 plies are too thick.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The geometry of the house is confusing a bit. It is a flat roof, sloping wall, two story home. A Mansard style. The roof load is supported by a carrier beam in the middle of the 2nd story room. The ceiling is 2x6, which carries over to the approximately 15 degree slanted walls. The end of the house, which is above the 12' span in question, used to be a balcony (no overhang) which was replaced with a flush dormer window area. So the 2nd story carrier beam terminates centrally above the 1st floor area in question.

Comment: This beam terminates into a 2x12 header on the second story, held with joist hanger. And the ends of this header carry down into the floor joist, which was reinforced creatively with some 2x8 sections and joist hangers. This was done retroactively since the original construction carried this load directly into the subfloor, between the joists! At any rate, the second story load from the roof, while not negligible, doesn't anecdotally seem to be too great. The roof is merely some iso board, epdm rubber, 1/2 ply, and 2x6x12's.

Comment: To clarify a question of yours, the plan would be to leave the existing header, truss, and 2x4 jack stud assembly as is. I would add to this by building a second header, truss, and 2x4 jack stud assembly in front of the other and nailing, lagging, gluing them together. This would be a functional assembly. The foundation beneath is wide enough that I could fit some sections of 2x8 under the floor where the jacks would come down to essentially create a couple of internal/redundant rim joists. This way, when the rim joists press down on the subfloor, there is actual support under them.

Comment: To further clarify, I would exactly duplicate the existing header assembly in front of the old one, extending into the room. And I would underpin every jack contact point beneath the subfloor by installing 2x8 wood sections on top of the foundation wall and sandwhiching them next to the rim joist, which is the only bearing support on this wall as is. I.e., header assembly bears down through jack studs, which sit on bottom plate, which sits on subfloor, which sits on rim joist, which sits on foundation wall top.)

Comment: It might be best to use LVL beams here. Ideally I would have done that to begin with but removing what is there isn't an option since the house is sided and finished outside. But I wonder if I could build a duplicate header like above out of 2 LVL 2x12 equivalents in front of the old one. I think either codes were more lax "back in the day" or this house was just underbuilt but I am really looking to put my mind at ease and avoid any possible strength related failures since this house will be lived in.

Comment: I edited a photo to reflect the true shape of the house. It is two stories, second story has slanted walls. Flat roof. 2,000 sq foot home.

Comment: @Jimmy, what I need is the tributary area of roof that loads the header and how that load is geometrically spread on the header. For the 2nd floor, the tributary area was half of the joist lengths ending in the carrier beam (the other half of the joist psf loading goes to the exterior wall) times half of the carrier beam's length (the other half of the carrier beam's pounds per foot loading goes to its end away from the header). Thus the (12ft/2 + 12ft/2)(12ft/2) = (12ft)(6ft) computation in my answer.

Comment: @Jimmy, from your description I can't confidently compute tributary area and load positions. For the roof, 10psf dead load and 20psf live load should convert these areas to loads (I assume by the flat roof that you have no snow load, correct?). It sounds like the roof framing layout is perfectly analogous to the floor framing layout. If that's the case, then the roof carrier beam's length is missing from your description. Your drawing is asymmetric. Is that correct? As drawn, the 12 ft header acts as a transfer beam for half the load of the 10 ft header applied 2ft from the 12 ft header's end.

Comment: @Jimmy, whoops, I understand that the roof header load comes down to a floor joist and travels from there to the 1st floor carrier beam and exterior walls. Are these loads applied asymmetrically as shown? 4 ft from the 1st floor carrier beam on one side and 6 ft from the 1st floor carrier beam on the other side?

Comment: @ popham the loads are applied symmetrically, I just poorly drew them. I did find some older schematics of the home and have added them above. The Floor 1 photo is what we have been discussing. And the Floor 2 photo has the "primary bedroom" which is above that area. The framing layout is the same on both floors, and I marked that up a bit in the photos.

Comment: And where the second story load is coming down from the carrier beam, picture two 2x8 sections of blocking next to each other supported by joist hangers on both ends sandwhiched between the joists directly under where that load is. Then as you say, it should in theory be carried by the joists over to the main carrier beam in that room, which sits atop the 1st floor header.

Comment: @Jimmy, the interior ends of the carrier beams from your schematic irritate me a little still. They have different connection details in the neighborhood of that chimney (I assume that black blob is a chimney)? The first floor header is drawn as 14'-9". Is that right? There's no post to shorten its span length to the 12'-0"? Squinting at the second floor header, I convert the 16'-7" to 13'-0" from the exterior wall to the beam span's interior end. Is that about right? And my assumption about zero snow load? Is that right?

Comment: Yes the carrier beam on floor one, which is 14' 9" terminates next to the chimney masonry by resting on several 2x4's there. Yes the second floor carrier beam is probably about 13'. I'm not sure about snow load. This is in the northeast, so it does snow though its been mild since I've owned the house.

Comment: @Jimmy, I hear "northeast" and my mind says "substantial snow load." In most bigger cities you can find the snow load by searching "[city name] snow load." If you can't figure it out, then name your state and county.

Comment: I was able to find pg = 30.0 psf for my zip